# How to compare data between periods?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to compare the growth rate of sale data between dates.

Schema (SQLite v3.39):

```
CREATE TABLE "VENTAS" (
    "date" TEXT,
    "code"  TEXT,
    "qty"   REAL,
    "cost"  REAL,
    "price" REAL
);

INSERT INTO "VENTAS" VALUES
("2022-01-01","MARIO", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-01-05","MARIO", -1, -1.00, -2.00),
("2022-01-09","LUIGI", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-01-23","LUIGI", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-01-30","PEACH", -1, -1.00, -2.00),
("2022-02-01","MARIO", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-02-11","MARIO", -1, -1.00, -2.00),
("2022-02-19","LUIGI", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-02-28","LUIGI", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-03-01","PEACH", -1, -1.00, -2.00),
("2022-03-15","MARIO", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-03-20","MARIO", -1, -1.00, -2.00),
("2022-03-29","LUIGI", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-04-09","LUIGI", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-04-12","PEACH", -1, -1.00, -2.00),
("2022-04-18","MARIO", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-04-22","MARIO", -1, -1.00, -2.00),
("2022-04-22","LUIGI", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-05-13","LUIGI", 1, 1.00, 2.00),
("2022-05-25","PEACH", -1, -1.00, -2.00);

SELECT code,
(SELECT SUM(qty) WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31') as qty,
(SELECT SUM(qty) WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28') as qty2,
(SELECT SUM((price * ABS(qty))) WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31') as sale,
(SELECT SUM((price * ABS(qty))) WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28') as sale2
FROM VENTAS
WHERE qty != 0
GROUP BY code;
```

Result:

| code | qty | qty2 | sale | sale2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LUIGI | 8 |  | 16 |  |
| MARIO | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| PEACH | -4 |  | -8 |  |

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WR23Q2xsSgVyMqKYxPx3d/9)

I expect:

| code | qty | qty2 | sale | sale2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LUIGI | 2 | 2 | 4.00 | 4.00 |
| MARIO | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| PEACH | -1 | 0 | -2.00 | 0 |

It is using entire sum instead of conforming to where clause.

Comment: This condition is wrong. Did you mean to write date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28'?

Comment: @forpas correct, I fixed it but it's still giving null

Comment: You also changed your sample data and now your expected results do not make sense.

Comment: @forpas i changed the raw data into 1s so it's easier to understand and test. sorry for the sudden changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT code,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31' THEN qty END) AS qty,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28' THEN qty END) AS qty2,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31' THEN price * ABS(qty) END) AS sale,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28' THEN price * ABS(qty) END) AS sale2
FROM VENTAS
WHERE qty <> 0
GROUP BY code;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xN0T-DD3).